# dhcp-request & ack flooding on openwrt

Tags: embedded-linux, openwrt, dhcp

I see these multiple (about 5-6) dhcp-request & ack messages on OpenWRT router; periodically.
This is happening with one particular android 4.4 mobile device.
Any idea why it should be happening?
I run a script at dhcp-ack event. These multiple requests are causing problems by calling the script too many times.

DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.7.39 5c:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.7.39 5c:2e:xx:xx:xx:xx 
... 
... 
DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.7.39 5c:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.7.39 5c:2e:xx:xx:xx:xx

Answer (score 0):

maybe the lease time out of this station and this station will send dhcp request for a new ip.